# Slack API - Get the users mentioned in the message (or reply)

Tags: slack-api

When sending a message (or reply), it's possible use this event:

https://api.slack.com/events/message

Is it possible to retrieve the list of users who have been mentioned in a message without to parse the message content?

Regards